# Converting Polar to Cartesian coordinates (0-360 degrees)

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am currently using the following code to convert from Cartesian (x, y) coordinates to an angle (0-360 degrees):

```
def anti_clockwise(x,y):
    alpha = degrees(atan2(y,x))
    return (alpha + 360) % 360
```

I am now trying to go back by specifying a distance (eg, 100) and angle (result from above code) to return to some x, y coordinates.

I have been able to get this to work using a simple trigonometry function, but this is limited to 0-90 degrees. Is there any way of getting the x, y coordinates for the full 0-360 degrees range?

Following is what I'm using but realized I didn't convert back to radians!

```
def get_coord(magnitude, degrees):
    angle = radians(degrees)
    x = magnitude * cos(angle)
    y = magnitude * sin(angle)
    return x, y
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help to show your attempt so we can help you figure out why it's only working for 0-90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I realised it needed to be converted back to radians for the calcs, so upated the code. I think it's working now up to 360 degrees, but would still appreciate any sort of confirmation on if this is the correct approach - as i'm struggling to test it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's the way I'd do it, except I'd double-check to see that you haven't switched `cos`/`sin` and the signs are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has been tested ans is working:

```
def get_coord(magnitude, degrees):
    angle = radians(degrees)
    x = magnitude * cos(angle)
    y = magnitude * sin(angle)
    return x, y
```

The problem was not converting to radians during the angle calculation.